# AttributeError - CBV 'function' object has no attribute 'as_view'

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I'm using a regular CBV in comination with a decorator and I always get this error:

> AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'as_view'

Here is my code:

```
@my_decorator
class MyView(View):
    template_name = 'package/index.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that CBVs work differently with `decorators` as FBVs.

Here's the way to go with it:

```
@method_decorator(my_decorator)
def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return super(MyView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

[Here is a link to the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class).

Comment: Or, decorate it in the urlconf: `url('my_url', method_decorator(MyView.as_view()))`.